# Converting GeoJSON to shapefile using GeoTools Java

Tags: shapefile, geojson, java, geotools

I am implementing a web service in Java which takes a GeoJSON file as input and converts it into a shapefile. My code looks something like this :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public String submit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap modelMap) throws IOException {
          modelMap.addAttribute("file", file);
          File ew = convert(file);
//        String[] cmd = {"-t_srs", "CRS:84", "-f", "GeoJSON","[name].geojson","[name].shp"};
//        ogr2ogr.main(cmd);
          toShp(ew);
          return "fileUploadView"; // ignore this return statement
      }
      public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException
      {    
          File convFile = new File("D:\\Gauravmmi\\0projects\\sample.GeoJSON");
          convFile.createNewFile(); 
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile); 
          fos.write(file.getBytes());
          fos.close(); 
          return convFile;
      }

            public static void toShp(File geojson) throws IOException {     
                File shpFile = new File("D:\\Gauravmmi\\0projects\\test.shp");
                ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

                Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
                params.put("url", shpFile.toURI().toURL());
                params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);
        /*
         * InputStream in = new FileInputStream(geojson); int decimals = 15;
         * GeometryJSON gjson = new GeometryJSON(decimals); FeatureJSON fjson = new
         * FeatureJSON(gjson);
         * 
         * FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> fc =
         * fjson.readFeatureCollection(in); fc.getSchema();
         * 
         * WriteShapefile writer = new WriteShapefile(shpFile);
         * writer.writeFeatures(fc);
         */   
                ShapefileDataStore shpDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore)  dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);


                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(geojson);
                int decimals = 15; 
                GeometryJSON gjson = new GeometryJSON(decimals); 
                FeatureJSON fjson = new FeatureJSON(gjson);

                FeatureCollection fc = fjson.readFeatureCollection(in);

                SimpleFeatureType type = (SimpleFeatureType) fc.getSchema();        
                shpDataStore.createSchema(type);

                Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

                String typeName = shpDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

                SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = shpDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

                if (featureSource instanceof FeatureStore) {
                    SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

                    featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
                    try {

                        featureStore.addFeatures(fc);

                        transaction.commit();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        transaction.rollback();

                    } finally {
                        transaction.close();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(typeName + " does not support read/write access");
                }


              }
```

And my sample GeoJSON looks something like this:-

```
  {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {   // no luck changing this to "the_geom"
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            72.99316406249999,
            27.449790329784214
          ],
          [
            78.134765625,
            27.68352808378776
          ],
          [
            77.5634765625,
            26.15543796871355
          ],
          [
            83.8037109375,
            24.806681353851964
          ],
          [
            84.111328125,
            26.82407078047018
          ],
          [
            86.2646484375,
            25.045792240303445
          ],
          [
            86.17675781249999,
            22.998851594142913
          ],
          [
            82.001953125,
            19.80805412808859
          ],
          [
            77.82714843749999,
            19.062117883514652
          ],
          [
            76.1572265625,
            16.25686733062344
          ],
          [
            77.2119140625,
            13.539200668930816
          ],
          [
            75.3662109375,
            14.43468021529728
          ],
          [
            74.970703125,
            17.476432197195518
          ],
          [
            75.05859375,
            19.766703551716976
          ],
          [
            73.47656249999999,
            21.248422235627014
          ],
          [
            71.5869140625,
            22.59372606392931
          ],
          [
            71.89453125,
            24.086589258228027
          ],
          [
            72.8173828125,
            26.902476886279832
          ],
          [
            74.92675781249999,
            22.998851594142913
          ],
          [
            75.8056640625,
            25.085598897064752
          ],
          [
            71.7462158203125,
            27.415662034561
          ],
          [
            73.531494140625,
            28.134971934813155
          ],
          [
            73.0206298828125,
            27.42053815128712
          ],
          [
            74.619140625,
            27.761329874505233
          ],
          [
            74.59167480468749,
            27.49365405370312
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I am running the sample GeoJSON through the controller I am getting five files in output (test.dbf,test.fix,test.prj,test.shp.test.shx) where test.prj contains nothing.
And so when I import this shapefile in QGIS I get nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code:

1. You never set the projection of your features so `test.prj` will be empty. It would be better to use the `gt-geojsondatastore` module to handle the GeoJSON import as it takes care of this for you.
2. The geometry attribute of a Shapefile must be called `the_geom` and you don't set this so QGis (and other GIS) can't find a geometry to be displayed.

Here is some code to do this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.collection.ListFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONDataStoreFactory;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureStore;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.feature.NameImpl;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeImpl;
import org.geotools.feature.type.GeometryDescriptorImpl;
import org.geotools.feature.type.GeometryTypeImpl;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.geotools.util.URLs;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.feature.type.AttributeDescriptor;
import org.opengis.feature.type.AttributeType;
import org.opengis.feature.type.GeometryDescriptor;
import org.opengis.feature.type.GeometryType;

public class GeoJsonToShp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // open geojson

    URL url = URLs.fileToUrl(new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.geojson"));
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(GeoJSONDataStoreFactory.URLP.key, url);
    DataStore in = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
    if (in == null) {
      throw new IOException("couldn't open datastore from " + url);
    }
    SimpleFeatureCollection features = in.getFeatureSource(in.getTypeNames()[0]).getFeatures();

    // convert schema for shapefile
    SimpleFeatureType schema = features.getSchema();
    GeometryDescriptor geom = schema.getGeometryDescriptor();

    List<AttributeDescriptor> attributes = schema.getAttributeDescriptors();
    GeometryType geomType = null;
    List<AttributeDescriptor> attribs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (AttributeDescriptor attrib : attributes) {
      AttributeType type = attrib.getType();
      if (type instanceof GeometryType) {
        geomType = (GeometryType) type;
      } else {
        attribs.add(attrib);
      }
    }

    GeometryTypeImpl gt = new GeometryTypeImpl(new NameImpl("the_geom"), geomType.getBinding(),
        DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, geomType.isIdentified(), geomType.isAbstract(), geomType.getRestrictions(),
        geomType.getSuper(), geomType.getDescription());

    GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = new GeometryDescriptorImpl(gt, new NameImpl("the_geom"), geom.getMinOccurs(),
        geom.getMaxOccurs(), geom.isNillable(), geom.getDefaultValue());

    attribs.add(0, geomDesc);

    SimpleFeatureType outSchema = new SimpleFeatureTypeImpl(schema.getName(), attribs, geomDesc, schema.isAbstract(),
        schema.getRestrictions(), schema.getSuper(), schema.getDescription());

    // create output datastore

    File outFile = new File("output.shp");
    outFile.createNewFile();
    FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(outFile);
    ds.createSchema(outSchema);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = ds.getFeatureSource();
    if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
      SimpleFeatureCollection collection;
      List<SimpleFeature> feats = new ArrayList<>();
      // retype the features
      try (FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> features2 = features.features()) {
        while (features2.hasNext()) {
          SimpleFeature f = features2.next();
          SimpleFeature reType = DataUtilities.reType(outSchema, f, true);

          reType.setAttribute(outSchema.getGeometryDescriptor().getName(),
              f.getAttribute(schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getName()));

          feats.add(reType);
        }
      }

      collection = new ListFeatureCollection(outSchema, feats);

      SimpleFeatureStore outStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

      outStore.addFeatures(collection);
      ds.dispose();
    } else {
      System.err.println("Unable to write to " + outFile);
    }
    in.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: unable to import import org.geotools.util.URLs and import org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONDataStoreFactory, can you suggest something?

Comment: for the datastore - <dependency>
   <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
   <artifactId>gt-geojsondatastore</artifactId>
   <version>${geotools.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: and for URLs - add gt-metadata but that should come with gt-main.

Comment: in case of URLs , it will be <dependency>
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>gt-metadata</artifactId> 
<version>16.2</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>gt-main</artifactId> 
<version>16.2</version> 
</dependency> Is this right?

Comment: For 16.2 you might need the older formulation which I can't recall - upgrade to 19 or 20

Comment: on upgrading to 19.0 its showing compilation error GeoJsonToShp.java:[40,50] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89380/discussion-between-gaurav-and-ian-turton).

Comment: Was trying out your code. However `GeoJSONDataStoreFactory.URLP` does not exist.

Comment: are you using a recent version of GeoTools - 21.x or 22.x?